# extension exception: 1944553 while applying raster netlogo gis

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am trying to load an ascii into Netlogo with apply-raster from the GIS extension.
While I did this many times before (although not with this specific ascii), netlogo now throws the following error:

```
extension exception: 1944553
error while observer running GIS:APPLY-RASTER
```

I am not sure why this is happening.
The ascii has a projection file with it (WKT), which should work fine:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

The ascii itself has these parameters:

```
ncols         1481
nrows         1314
xllcorner     -10.577897001
yllcorner     49.902509998994
cellsize      0.00833333333333
NODATA_value  -9999
```

I am running these four lines for loading the ascii and resizing the world.

```
set my-dataset "data/my-folder/my-file.asc"
resize-world 0 gis:width-of (gis:load-dataset my-dataset) - 1 0 gis:height-of (gis:load-dataset my-dataset) - 1
gis:set-world-envelope-ds (gis:envelope-of (gis:load-dataset my-dataset))
gis:apply-raster (gis:load-dataset my-dataset) my-variable
```

Is anyone familiar with this error?
Or is there a place where I can look up what this extension exception means? I could not find it, but maybe I am looking in the wrong places.

Thanks!

edit:
See below for the details of the error

```
Extension exception: 1944553
error while observer running GIS:APPLY-RASTER
  called by procedure LOAD-DATASETS
  called by procedure CREATE-WORLD
  called by Button 'create-world'

org.nlogo.nvm.EngineException: Extension exception: 1944553
 at org.nlogo.agent.World.fastGetPatchAt(World.java:560)
 at org.nlogo.agent.World.fastGetPatchAt(World.java:35)
 at org.myworldgis.netlogo.ApplyRaster.performInternal(ApplyRaster.java:53)
 at org.myworldgis.netlogo.GISExtension$Command.perform(GISExtension.java:63)
 at org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:54)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
 at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)

NetLogo 5.2.0
main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame
thread: JobThread
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_45 (Sun Microsystems Inc.; 1.6.0_45-b06)
operating system: Windows 7 6.1 (x86 processor)
Scala version 2.9.2
JOGL: (3D View not initialized)
OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not initialized)
model: test_run_world

03:23:17.778 SwitchedTabsEvent (org.nlogo.app.Tabs) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 RuntimeErrorEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.window.ChooserWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.window.InputBoxWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.window.InputBoxWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.window.ChooserWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.window.ChooserWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.window.ChooserWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
03:23:17.778 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.widget.SwitchWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
```

Comment: The error looks to me like the problem is in the GIS extension; the extension is computing out-of-bounds values for pxcor and/or pycor and then trying to access a non-existent patch. I don't know GIS stuff or the extension's guts, so I couldn't speculate about why that might be. At minimum, it ought to give a comprehensible error message in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was finally solved after recreating all ascii files. Even though there was no apparent difference in the old and new ascii files, the old files must have been corrupted somehow. The code in the question works fine now. Hopefully this topic is still helpful for anybody running into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is an off-by-one error in RasterDataset.resample, but I've never had the time to look into it. You should be able to work around this issue by removing the "- 1"'s from your call to resize-world, i.e.,

```
resize-world 0 gis:width-of (gis:load-dataset my-dataset) 0 gis:height-of (gis:load-dataset my-dataset)
```

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll see if I can find time to investigate further.

Comment: Eric, perhaps you could open a ticket on this presumed issue at https://github.com/netlogo/gis-extension/issues ? Even if it's a vague issue that just says whatever you can remember about it, on a for-whatever-it's-worth basis?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried to see if the ascii's were the problem, but running it over different files did not solve it. However, recreating the ascii's solved it, with no apparent change visible. I tried to identify any differences so it could be helpful here, but could not detect anything. Somehow, the first files must have been corrupted. The "-1" is there because the netlogo world starts at 0, while the gis:width-of an ascii starts at 1. Not having the "-1" in place would result in a world which is 1 to large.