# PIxel size of raster changes when exporting it from NetLogo

Tags: gis, netlogo, raster

I have a raster with a resolution of 220m that I import into NetLogo and then export with some results in each cell. However, on exporting, the pixel size changes to somewhere between 219 and 220 m, with the result that there is a slight misalignment when placing it on other layers.

Is there a fix for this?

EDIT: 
Here's the code I used to import the raster:

```
set rasterLayer gis:load-dataset "x.asc"
resize-world 0 gis:width-of rasterLayer 0 gis:height-of rasterLayer
gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of rasterLayer
gis: apply-raster rasterLayer patchVariableA
```

And this is the code to export the raster:

```
set tempRaster gis:patch-dataset patchVariableB
gis:store-dataset tempRaster "output"
```

Here "x.asc" is the raster layer with a resolution of 220 by 220 meters and "output" is the exported raster layer that has a resolution of 219.7 by 219.7 meters.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you are using the `gis` extension, and that by "220m", you mean 220 meters?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: What does "the pixel size changes" means? Can you be more specific? What even is "pixel size"? Can you show the code you are using? It's really hard to answer questions that don't include the code where the problem is.

Comment: By pixel size, I mean the size of a single raster cell (or its resolution). The raster has a cell size of 220 x 220 meters, but when it is exported from NetLogo, it has a cell size of 219.7 to 219.7 meters.

This is the code I use to import the raster:

`set rasterLayer gis:load-dataset "x.asc" 
resize-world 0 gis:width-of rasterLayer 0 gis:height-of rasterLayer
gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of rasterLayer
gis: apply-raster rasterLayer patchVariableA`

Comment: And this is the code I use to export the raster:

`set tempRaster gis:patch-dataset patchVariableB
gis:store-dataset tempRaster "output"`

Here "x.asc" is the raster layer with a resolution of 220 by 220 meters and "output" is the exported raster layer with a resolution of 219.7 by 219.7 meters.

Comment: perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437711/extension-exception-1944553-while-applying-raster-netlogo-gis

Comment: Did you solve or undestood what happened?